# Trying to wrap requests but getting AttributeError: type object 'http_req' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any suggestions as to where I am getting this wrong?  I'm trying to wrap the Python requests.get, request.post, requests.delete etc

```
(venv3.4)ubuntu@mail:~$ cat sav.py
import requests

class http_req():
    # this wrap requests so we can print warnings on exceptions instead of crashing out

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.http_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'options']

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.http_methods:
            request_method_to_call = getattr(requests, name)
            return request_method_to_call(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        raise AttributeError()

print('Test 1: showing first 10 characters of response')
print(requests.get('http://www.google.com').text[:10])

print('Test 2: showing first 10 characters of response')
t = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
print(t.text[:10])

print('Test 3: showing first 10 characters of response')
http_req.get('http://www.google.com')

print('Test 4: showing first 10 characters of response')
t = http_req.get('http://www.google.com')

(venv3.4)ubuntu@mail:~$ python sav.py
Test 1: showing first 10 characters of response
<!doctype
Test 2: showing first 10 characters of response
<!doctype
Test 3: showing first 10 characters of response
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sav.py", line 25, in <module>
    http_req.get('http://www.google.com')
AttributeError: type object 'http_req' has no attribute 'get'
(venv3.4)ubuntu@mail:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

As you uses an instance object when checking if HTTP method exists in a instace attribute (that is, **self.http_methods**), you must firstly create the object and then call to **obej.get()** method. Otherwise the IF expression is bypassed and **AttributeError** is raised.  So it should be:

```
import requests

class http_req():
    # this wrap requests so we can print warnings on exceptions instead 
    # of crashing out
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.http_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'options']
        self.data = None # response data

    def response(self):
        return self.data

    def __getattr__(self, name):        
        if name in self.http_methods:
            request_method_to_call = getattr(requests, name)
            self.data = request_method_to_call(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            return self.response            
        raise AttributeError()



print('Test 3: showing first 10 characters of response')
t = http_req('http://www.google.com').get()
print(t.text[:10])
```

Also, as the expected attribute is a callable - in this case - you must to return a callable from _ *getattr* _() descriptor. And that is why self.response method is returned.

Comment: I am trying to replace the "request.get" of test1 with "http_req.get" because my code base is littered with calls to requests that don't have exception handling and I wanted to search and replace with a drop in replacement. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: @DukeDougal I'm sorry, Duke. But I advise you open another question as long as this one is nothing to do with the current question. ;)